# Fujitsu Lifebook A514 Setup Warning Boot Failure

Tags: boot, bios, hard-drive-failure

Day before yesterday, everything was working without a problem. My notebook ([Fujitsu A514 Lifebook](http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/products/computing/pc/notebooks/lifebook-a514/)) was running Debian testing amd64 on kernel 4.2. I put it to upgrade, and it ran completely. Then suddenly, yesterday, when I booted up the laptop in the morning, I got the totally unexpected error.

> Warning Bootable device was not found. [Continue]

On continuing, it gave me the list of the bootable drives

1. Kingston SSD 120G
2. CD/DVD Drive
3. Network

Selecting the Kingston (my primary boot drive)  gives

> Setup Warning Boot failure [Continue]

Initially, thinking it to be a data glitch, I wiped the drive completely, and installed Debian 8 again. Installation goes smooth, as it should on a 25 days old SSD, but on booting the OS from drive, same error.

Doubting a dead SSD, I replaced the drive with a WD 500GB hard disk and tried to boot from it, but exact same error. In both the cases, the SSD and the HDD are detected by the BIOS, the installation goes smooth, with no errors when partitioning and stuff, but fails when booting from drive.

Today, I installed Ubuntu 15.10 that I freshly downloaded, and installed it to the drive. The installation went smooth, and successfully, but like the case with Debian, on rebooting to drive, I got the "Warning Bootable device was not found. [Continue]" error.

My notebook is 25 days old, so the possibility of a disk failure (in fact, 2 brand new disks) is pretty low. I searched nearly every forum with similar title but nothing worked.

Summary of what I tried:

- Doing complete wipes, reinstalling from multiple ISOs to minimize the
  possibility of corrupt image.
- Tried BIOS and UEFI
- Tested multiple drives to make sure it is not a dead drive.
- BIOS reset.
- Battery Removal and reinsertion suggested on some forum.

I think the BIOS is not getting the path to the OS (I completely lack the knowledge about the boot up procedure), or something is preventing it from doing so.

Tried Fujitsu's support number, but didn't connect. I am really out of ideas right now, and hence this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Looked like the efi partition was messed up. I booted into recovery from my debian 8 live CD, forced grub2 reinstall and the notebook was working back like normal. Hope that helps.